# Fetch permalink of every posts in newsfeed via jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-extension

I'm a newbie trying to code a Chrome Extension for facebook.

My requirements
1. Display a 'string' near Like/Share/Comment area (class='uiStreamFooter' found in HTML)
2. Link the string to the permalink of the post.

I've done both. Here's the problem I'm facing :

```
  $('.genericStreamStory').each(function(){
       var link = $('.uiStreamSource').find('a').attr('href');
       $('.uiStreamFooter').append("<span class='string'><a href='"+ link +"'>Permalinked String</a></span>");  
});
```

What I'm trying to do here is to find 'each' element with 'genericStreamStory' class, append a string called 'Permalinked String' to the SPAN element 'uiStreamFooter' that is found in every post (with class = genericStreamStory).

I'm able to get the string under all the posts in my newsfeed. 
**But, the link (for all the posts) is just the Permalink of the First post!**

I'm sure it has to be something to do with jQuery selection and traversal only. 
Couldn't much figure it out myself.

*.genericStreamStory* - the class for every facebook post
*.uiStreamSource* - the span that holds an anchor for the permalink
*.uiStreamFooter* - the span that holds the Like, Comment, Share buttons where I intend to add my 'String'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.genericStreamStory').each(function(){
   var link = $('.uiStreamSource').find('a').attr('href');
```

You are not limiting the search for `.uiStreamSource` elements here to the specific `.genericStreamStory` – so it just gets you the attribute of the first element found in the document.

So use something like

```
var link = $(this).find('.uiStreamSource a').attr('href');
```

instead, that should work as you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.genericStreamStory').each(function(){
       var link = $(this).find('.uiStreamSource a').attr('href');
       $(this).find('.uiStreamFooter').append("<span class='string'><a href='"+ link +"'>Permalinked String</a></span>");  
});
```